# Get Y coordinate of motion touch event android

Tags: android, textview, motionevent

There is an image exist. I try to press the the top part of the image. The value i get is from motion event:

```
e.getY()
```

The value is not the same as the value I got from getTop();

```
textview.getTop();
```

Below is my code:

```
    public class level1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        String firstWord = dbHandler.getWord(1);
        String[] firstWordArray = firstWord.split("-");
        ArrayList<String[]> finalWord = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < firstWordArray.length; i++) {
            finalWord.add(firstWordArray[i].split(","));
        }

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        int x1 = textview.getLeft();
        int y1 = textview.getTop();

        int x2 = textview.getRight();
        int y2 = textview.getBottom();

        float width = x2 - x1;
        float height = y2 - y1;

        Log.i("Height",""+y1);
        Log.i("Height",""+y2);
        Log.i("Height",""+e.getY());
        Log.i("Height",""+textview.getY());
        Log.i("Height",""+textview.getHeight());
        Log.i("Height",""+height);
        Log.i("Width",""+x1);
        Log.i("Width",""+x2);
        Log.i("Width",""+e.getX());
        Log.i("Width",""+textview.getWidth());
        Log.i("Width",""+width);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(level1.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Root Word");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        if (finalWord.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < finalWord.size(); i++) {
                float x = e.getX();
                float y = e.getY();
                float xVar = 100*(x-x1)/width;
                float yVar = 100*(y-y1)/height;
                if (xVar< (Integer.parseInt(finalWord.get(i)[0]))) {
                    if (yVar < (Integer.parseInt(finalWord.get(i)[1]))) {
                        dialogButton.setText(finalWord.get(i)[2]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY()) is what you are looking for?</strike>

The difference between the values comes from that the `MotionEvent`'s `getY()` return the event Y coordinate, but the `TextView`'s `getTop()` method return the Y position **relative to its parent**.

Let's say your layout is look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this case when you click on the TextView the `getTop()` return 0 because this is the very first (and top) view of its parent. But if you add another TextView to your layout similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Another text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you now click the TextView with "Click me!" text, `getTop()` will return non zero value (in my case 38) because the height of the other TextView.

Do you want to value where you touched the image?

Comment: Both the e.getX() and e.getRawX() return the same value but the value is very different from textView.getTop()

Comment: I understand your explanation.This was the explanation that I was looking for. I created an onTouch event listener for the textView. So now the e.getY() will return the value relative to the textView.